for which p is the infinite series of sin(1/n^p) convergent?
How could one study the convergence of the following infinite series: $$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\frac{1}{n^p}$$
i assume neither LCT nor DCT are not applicable here, any other tools I know, such as Term Test, Cauchy Test, D'Alambert test give no results.
I want to understand how the convergence changes based on the exponent of n:
i. e. For which $p$ do the series of the following shape converge?
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\frac{1}{n^p}$$
Abel's or Dirichlet's test are also not applicable so I'm pretty much stuck.

well it does, but not explicitly, since I wanted to figure out for which exponents is the given series convergent, I think I will paraphrase my question to address that aspect only. Thank you btw

okay I figured myself:
since $\frac{1}{n^p}$ tends to 0 we can rewrite  $
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\frac{1}{n^p}$ as:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}×\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n^p}}{\frac{1}{n^p}}
$$ and the second part will tend to 1, thus, the series will be equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$ which converges when $p>1$ and diverges else.  So the proof uses LCT, actually.
